# Qt build both release and debug libraries

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I needed to install Qt SDK to Redhat backend machine which does not have a GUIs. (Amazon ec2). When I tried to install it failed due to fail to connect display.

Then I tried to download the source and compile. If I use configure -debug, it only compile debug libraries. Same as it compiles and install release binaries only if I specify -release. Also in my *.pro file it links the last installed build without considering CONFIG += debug or CONFIG += release

I need both formats. libQt5Core.so and libQt5Core.d.so. And need to link separate libs according to the CONFIG.

Comment: how to build existing software packages is more a question for super user or another stack exchange site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the issue doing this.

- First I configured `configure -debug -qtlibinfix .d` and installed.
- Then I configured `configure -release` and installed again.

Now I have two binaries `*.d.so` for debug and `*.so` for release in `/usr/local/Qt-5.6.0`.

Then edited `/usr/local/Qt-5.6.0/mkspecs/features/qt.prf` and replaced

```
MODULE_MODULE = $$eval(QT.$${QTLIB}.module)
```

with

```
MODULE_MODULE =
    debug: MODULE_MODULE = $$eval(QT.$${QTLIB}.module).d
    else: MODULE_MODULE = $$eval(QT.$${QTLIB}.module)
```

If I used `CONFIG += debug` in *.pro file, it links with `*.d.so`. Otherwise it links with `*.so`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want both sets of libraries you can use the `configure -debug-and-release` option. Take a look at the [Configuration Options for Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/configure-options.html) for more options.

Comment: It is only for Mac OX. I tried it before and it gives this output
`WARNING: -debug-and-release is not supported outside of Mac OS X.
Qt can be built in release mode with separate debug information, so
-debug-and-release is not necessary anymore
`

Comment: configure -h also say that
`-debug-and-release . Compile and link two versions of Qt, with and without
                         debugging turned on (Mac only).`

Comment: What version are you trying to build?